# How do I fetch all records which belong to a user and show only the records with distinct name?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-design

```
Tagmap.where(user_id: current_user.id).uniq(:name)
```

This query doesn't seem to work. It still fetches all the records belonging to that user only.

Comment: meaning multiple records belonging to that user have the same name? a bit more detail would be nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the group by SQL query.

```
Tagmap.where(user_id: current_user.id).group(:name)
```